# Rails, how to get 1.day.from_now at a set time (morning)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I currently queue my DelayedJob like so:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue MyJob.new, 5, 1.day.from_now
```

I'm looking for a way to set a different execution time:

```
Tomorrow morning at 9:30am PST
```

Does Rails have a helper that can take care of this? Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your rails server is **not** running in PST/PDT:

```
Time.use_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)") { 1.day.from_now.beginning_of_day + 9.5.hours }
```

If it is already running in PST/PDT, you can shorten it to:

```
1.day.from_now.beginning_of_day + 9.5.hours
```

Have a look at [Time](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html) and [TimeZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html) for more info.